# add zero to certain values in vector

Tags: r

My dataframe consists of three and four digit values. I want to paste 0 to the beginning of all the three digit values only. My df:

```
df1 %>% head()
  values    
   <ch>     
   2355
   560
   6699
   322
   0923
   804
```

I want to end up with this:

```
df1 %>% head()
  values    
   <ch>     
   2355
   0560
   6699
   0322
   0923
   0804
```

This is what I have tried:

```
subset %>%
    filter(
      str_detect(values, '^...$')
          )
```

But when I try to pipe the paste0 function I get an error back. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: `sprintf('%04i', df$values)` or even `formatC(a, width = 4,flag='0')`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, based on `stringr::str_pad`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(values = str_pad(values, width = 4, pad = "0", side = "left"))

#>   values
#> 1   2355
#> 2   0560
#> 3   6699
#> 4   0322
#> 5   0923
#> 6   0804
```